# Extract Data from a Text File - Data is in a Strange Format

Tags: python

I have a text file that is comprised of integers and their corresponding countries. How can I import/read the data and load it into a Python data structure, e.g. two lists, a dictionary, data frame?

[image]

Comment: It's just a text file so just read it line by line then split resulting strings on `=` sign, `strip()` spaces from around values and put values in two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
codes = []
countries = []

with open('blablabla', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        codes.append(line.split('=')[0].strip())
        countries.append(line.split('=')[1].strip()
```